# Why does round(143.23,-1) return 140?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, rounding

For the query

```
SELECT round(143.23, -1)
FROM   dual
```

I thought that the output will be 142 but the output i got is 140
can anyone help me by explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter indicates how many digits of precision **after** the decimal point you want to preserve. Thus, `-1` means one digit **before** the decimal point. I.e., you're losing the "ones" digit and rounding to the nearest "tens", resulting in `140`.

To get a whole number (`143` in this case), you can pass 0 as the second parameter, or just omit it entirely, as that's the default.

Comment: 143 in this case. Maybe they were looking for `round(143.23) -1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer martin

Comment: @MartinSmith or perhaps `round(143.23 - 1)`.